# Trying to duplicate a sheet onto a new file, then delete the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So here's my problem- my function copies my data, format and then creates it onto a new spreadsheet, deletes the copy.

However...in the copy, it copies my formulas rather than values meaning that I just get a load of reference errors.

Any ideas?

```
function copySpreadsheet(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Get current active sheet.
var sheet_name = ss.getRange("b4").getValue(); //
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Student Overview Spreadsheets").next(); // Get the ID of the folder where you will place a copy of the spreadsheet.
var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheet_name); // create new blank spreadsheet in a root folder
var asFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSS.getId()); // get new spreadsheet as a file
var sourceRange = ss.getRange("a1");
var targetRange = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1);
targetRange.setValues(sourceRange.getValues());
sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
true);

folder.addFile(asFile); // add this file to destination folder

DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(asFile); // remove a file from root folder

var copiedSheet = ss.copyTo(newSS); // copy active sheet to new spreadsheet
copiedSheet.setName(sheet_name); // rename copied sheet
newSS.deleteSheet(newSS.getSheetByName('Sheet1')); // remove "Sheet1" sheet which was created by default in new spreadsheet

}
```

Comment: Try using getDisplayValues()

Comment: Just copy-paste as values. Use the macro recorder to learn the syntax like:  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES